# Pivot a table 4 rows at a time

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, data-scrubbing

I'm trying to figure out how to pivot a table in SQL Server in the following way:

[image]

Every time the value is "PEAK", I want it to start on a new row. Essentially it would look like this.

`col1  col2  col3  col4
119   KH    ON    PEAK
4     K1    ON    PEAK
356   KH    OFF   PEAK
38    K1    ...   ...`

Comment: What determines the order of the source column?

Comment: A string starts as '119-KH-ON-PEAK|4-K1-ON-PEAK|356-KH-OFF-PEAK|38-K1-' and I'm tryinig to break it down into a table. I wrote a function to split it by a delimiter. First I split it by pipe then I split it by hyphen.

Comment: Probably is easier to modify that function to do what you want rather than having 2 steps.

Comment: Ok, but after you split by hyphen, what determines the order?  A table, by definition, is an *unordered* set of records.  If you split by hyphen and don't preserve the record number somehow, you can't guarantee your results will be in the same order.

Comment: For that matter, I'm assuming that when you split by pipe that the order doesn't matter then, too.  Is that the case or are you expecting a table to preserve that order there, too?

Comment: I guess I'm not sure how to answer your question other than than the order always follows exactly how it appears in the string as you read it from left to right

Comment: use rownum and mod 4 -.0001 and cast to an int round down.  then pivot on the row num group by the calculated value.

Comment: After I split by pipe and insert those values into a table variable, I cross apply the function splitting by hyphen. I don't have any order by clauses because I want to preserve the order the values appeared in the string

Comment: Thanks @xQbert I'll give that a try

Comment: @xQbert you should write that as an answer.

Comment: @RossPresser  It wasn't complete and as I can't get SQLServer working on SQLfiddle, I'll post most of the answer and let the author go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I'd really like to know how the source data is stored.. This seems like an awful lot of work when if the data is already stored in the correct rows splitting it there would be far easier...

Roughly here's how I'd have to do it...  All but the pivot is done...

```
select bar, (row_number() over (order by a.b)-.001)/4 grpOrder,
floor((row_number() over (order by a.b)-.001)/4) as grp
from foo
cross join (Select 1 as b) a
```

Here's a screenshot from an oracle attempt I can't get SQL fiddle to work with SQL server right now.

[image]

From here you could pivot the data based on the decimal values of morder and each row would be based on grp.

I had to use a cross join to get a value to order by but I needed it to be consistant so the order of the table foo would be preserved though this is by no means guaranteed.  I would recommend adding an ID or sequence to your split data otherwise the order could get corrupted.  If this is done we wouldn't need the cross join anymore. and the order by in the over order by could be set to that autonumber value.

I'm assuming from here you could figure out how to pivot. as each decimal value value of MOrder will be the same within each group.

and for the full pivot (again using oracle)

[image]

If your # of values in each group is dynamic, then we'd have to write some dynamic SQL to handle those situations; I've not done that here.

Comment: Personally I think that `(row_number() - 1) / 4` and `(row_number() - 1) % 4` are cleaner than all the math with decimals.